# Debian - System (audio) Settings breaking when starting/stopping LXC

Tags: debian, audio, lxc, settings

I'm rather new to Linux, recently having to start using it to make something for work (controlling Linux Containers). I'm on debian:

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've been messing around with containers for about a month now (mainly in a VM, but when I installed Debian natively, it worked as well), and only today has it started acting strange.

Whenever I try to start or stop a container -- both from the command line or using Python -- my sound suddenly stops working, and my System Settings window closes down. I've made sure the audio isn't in any way attached to a container (I deleted them all, rebooted, and created new containers). All other hardware seems to be fine - mouse and keyboard (which are both USB), and monitor.

**This is the system settings window before I run the command:**

[image]

**This is immediately after *(the settings window closes)*:**

[image]

**And this is what happens when I try reopening the System Settings window:**

[image]

On top of that, when I ran the command

```
$ lxc-start -n test1
```

It just hangs indefinitely - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, etc. do not work.

When I reboot it's all fixed - but it happens every time. What is going on?